# Removing time from datestamp with twig

Tags: twig, prestashop-1.7

I am using prestashop 1.7 which now uses twig (not sure what version).

I have the following in a twig file :

```
{{ customerInformation.personalInformation.registrationDate }}
```

which gives me:

```
29/01/2020 11:04:38
```

(so the date in DD-MM-YYYY-TIME format).

Does anyone know how to remove the time from the date?

e.g. so it just echo's

```
29/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store dates as a valid `DateTime` notation, then you could just use the [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) filter

```html
{{ '01/29/2020 10:00:00' | date('d/m/Y') }}
{{ '2020-01-29 10:00:00' | date('d/m/Y') }}
{{ '29-01-2020 10:00:00' | date('d/m/Y') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/20cy90)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `slice` filter (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) with something like this :

```
{{ customerInformation.personalInformation.registrationDate|slice(0,10) }}
```

This will return 10 characters, beginning at character at offset 0, that is to say from the beginning of the string.